# Can you add dimensions to the default lambda metrics (error, latency, invocations, etc.)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We currently have alarms set up for the default lambda metrics (error, latency, invocations, etc.). We also have custom metrics (we use Boto3 and record the metrics via `client.put_metric_data(Namespace=namespace, MetricData=metric_data)`) and alarms for those as well with the specific dimensions we need:

```
  USMaxRangeAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: 'US max range is over expected levels'
      AlarmName: 'USMaxRange'
      Namespace: MyService.MyLambda
      MetricName: max_range
      Dimensions:
        - Name: Country
          Value: US
      Period: 60 # seconds
      Statistic: Maximum
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Threshold: 5
      Unit: Seconds
      DatapointsToAlarm: 3
      EvaluationPeriods: 5
      TreatMissingData: notBreaching
```

Is there a way to split up *default* lambda metrics by custom dimensions as well so we don't have to create several new custom metrics to replace the defaults?

For example, we get passed in the country when the Lambda is called, and we want to be able to see the metric for errors *per country* rather than for the entire Lambda (same for latency and invocations). My first thought was to create new metrics and manually collect the data via custom metrics, but I wanted to sanity check that there was no better built-in way to do it first. I haven't seen anything in any of the documentation.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: I ended up just creating new metrics and created alarms (with metric math) grouping things as needed. I half expected this, but figured it was worth checking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to split up default lambda metrics by custom dimensions

Sadly there is no such way. But maybe you can create new metrics or alarms based on [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html).